# How to merge two values into an intersection type in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3

Suppose we have the following code:

```scala
object Main extends App {

  sealed trait A
  final case class A1(a1: Int) extends A
  final case class A2(a2: Int) extends A

  final case class B(b: Int)

  val a: A = A1(1)
  val b: B = B(2)
  val c: (A & B) = ???
}
```

Is it possible to create a value of type `A & B` from values `a` and `b`?

Comment: In short, no I don't think it's possible, and in principle I don't see how it even could or should be possible. On the JVM, which classes and interfaces something extends isn't alterable at runtime, not even by reflection.